# Showcasing exemplary questions and answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

I wanted to highlight this question about the J curve of alcohol consumption as one of the exemplary questions AND answers for our goal scope:

[Has the (in)famous J-shaped curve with regard to alcohol consumption and life expectancy been finally disproven?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17546/has-the-infamous-j-shaped-curve-with-regard-to-alcohol-consumption-and-life-ex)

and vote to use it as one of our examples in our tour pages, etc.

Currently the highest-voted questions are mostly outside our new scope, unfortunately.  **Is there any way (or any*where*) to highlight questions/answers that we want to use as examples of our new scope?**

Answer (score 4):

Moderators can change the example question on the tour, so, **yes, there is a way.** Unfortunately, the [sample Q&A](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17546) you proposed is ineligible.

From [What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/241919), these are the criteria for questions to be eligible:

> Apparently the posts have to be short, with at least two short answers (<=400 chars). They also shouldn't have any crazy formatting.

and [the SE Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/health/query/92078/possible-about-questions) to find it. Unfortunately (again), as of current writing, looks like none are eligible.

---

Apart from that, I'm not sure what else can be done. It's possible for mods to change some sections on the Help Center, perhaps by providing a meta link to "exemplary Q&A" post. However, this needs to be discussed more with the regulars and mods.

Comment: Seems to me you reference outdated info. We tried this multiple times: shoehorn posts that would violate our standards to replace the unicorn schmutz. The latest attempt is here [How do I determine a target time frame for breastfeeding?](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/3557) Look at the revisions! It should have been eligible? (++On other sites like Skeptics) it looks like these criteria are relaxed?)

Comment: @LangLangC apparently you're right, [Skeptics requested to lax the criteria](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/update-the-example-of-the-2-minute-tour#comment12868_2921): "*If I remember correctly, we asked SE to flip a switch that reduces the strict eligibility criteria, as we had not a single allowed question. You'll have to do the same thing on Health.*" We need SE's response for this...

Answer (score 2):

Could we not have a wiki meta post (Example Question: What questions are good questions for this site which also have good answers?) which we could link to in our tour and help pages, listing exemplary Q&As as examples?

Surely that would overcome the problem with the character and formatting restrictions we have along with Skeptics.  The only thing is that it would need to be regularly monitored for updates which may give the wrong impression.